# Vagrant port fowarding on macOS?

Tags: macos, postgresql, vagrant

I'm running postgresql on a Vagrant centos 7.2 box on macOS. I have confirmed postgres is up and running on the Vagrant box on port 5432 by connecting to it using `psql` on the box itself. I am attempting to forward port 5432 on the Vagrant box to port 10001 on my host machine as follows:

```
config.vm.define "acc_db" do | acc_db |
    acc_db.vm.box = "bento/centos-7.2"
    acc_db.vm.hostname = "acc.db"
    acc_db.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 5432, host: 10001

    acc_db.vm.provision "shell",
        inline: "yum upgrade -y -q --nogpgcheck"

    acc_db.vm.provision "shell",
        path: "install_postgres.sh"
```

I have altered my `pg_hba.conf` to bind to all ip addresses and allow password authentication, as below:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 ident
```

I have turned off the firewall but I am still unable to connect to postgres on port 10001 on the host machine:

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.10001"?
```

How do I fix this so that port forwarding works?

I have seen https://gielberkers.com/fixing-vagrant-port-forwarding-osx-yosemite/ but haven't tried it as it involves touching files I'm unfamiliar with. Is it the correct approach? It looks like you have to explicitly allow every port you want to forward via Vagrant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`...connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.10001"` means that you are not attempting a TCP/IP connection, so port forwarding cannot happen.

By default, `psql` use [Unix domain sockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket) on unix-like OSes.

Use the `-h` option of psql to specify a host, presumably `127.0.0.1` if using IPv4.

---

Additionally, the PostgreSQL server must listen to the network interface to which the connection will be routed. By default, it listens only to `localhost` for security reasons.
Setting `listen_addresses='*'` in `postgresql.conf` makes it listen on all existing interfaces.

Comment: Thanks. I put the -h option in: `psql -h 127.0.0.1 -p 10001 -u username` and I  get `psql: server closed the connection unexpectedly`. I don't see any errors in the postgres logs.

Comment: @user783836: do you have `listen_addresses='*'` in `postgresql.conf` to make it listen on all interfaces?

Comment: Works like a charm after editing `listen-addresses='*'`!